# Plugin Embed Any Document do not show for user

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress, and have an Embed Any Document plugin.

But if user not "ADMIN" it will not show this button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please add the code below to your theme's functions. It will remove the button for users who are not admins.

```
function RemoveAddMediaButtonsForNonAdmins() {
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
remove_action( 'media_buttons', 'media_buttons' );
if ( class_exists( 'Awsm_embed' ) ) {
remove_action( 'media_buttons', array( Awsm_embed::get_instance(), 'embedbutton' ), 1000 );
}
}
}
add_action('admin_head', 'RemoveAddMediaButtonsForNonAdmins');
```